# Clear data from the table and localStorage by ID. using the button

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom-events, javascript-objects

I need advice. I have a table, I store items in it, which are stored in localStorage and then inserted into the table. I need to set the delete button in the list. In order for it to work, when I click on it, the given row is deleted from both localStorage and the table.

```js
let form = document.querySelector("#form-list")


if(localStorage.getItem("task") == null){
    var taskArray = []
} else {
    taskArray = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("task"))
}

form.addEventListener("submit", function(event){
    // event.preventDefault()
    
    taskArray.push({
        id: uuidv4(),
        job: event.target.elements.selected.value,
        task: event.target.elements.text.value
    })
        
        // Clear the input and select boxes
        event.target.elements.selected.value = ""
        event.target.elements.text.value = ""

        // save localStorage
        taskArrayJSON = JSON.stringify(taskArray)
        localStorage.setItem("task", taskArrayJSON)

})

const buildTable = function(){
    let table = document.getElementById("table")

    for(let i = 0; i < taskArray.length; i++){
        var row = `<tr>
                    <td>${taskArray[i].job}</td>
                    <td>${taskArray[i].task}</td>
                    <td><button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="deleteButton(this)">Delete</button></td>
                  </tr>`
        table.innerHTML += row
    }
}

buildTable(taskArray)

const deleteButton = function(row){
    let table = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("task"))
    localStorage.removeItem("id")
    table.splice(row, 1)
    localStorage.setItem("task", JSON.stringify(table)) 
    



}
//Podle ID najdeme index daného jména a pomocí splice ho odstraníme
const removeTask = function(id){
    const index = taskArray.filter(function(nameTask){
        return nameTask.id === id
    })

    if(index > -1){
        taskArray.splice(index,1)
    }
}
```

Comment: Please share HTML code, too - and make a code snippet if possible.

Comment: ok HTML code share

Comment: https://codepen.io/Ondranemec91/pen/ZEyxBrG

Answer (score 1):

As far as I figure out, you can delete your row from your taskArray, and finally save it in the local like before. (meybe meke the local task empty and save it again)

to find out that you wanna delete which row, I suggest to set a data-id attribute on your row and when you clicked on delete button, get this data-id and according to it, delete the row.

Answer (score 0):

```
<h1>Table</h1>

<form id="form-list">
    <div class="form-group mx-auto col-3" style="margin-top: 2rem;">
        <select name="selected" class="form-select">
            <option selected>Open this select menu</option>
            <option value="Programování">Programování</option>
            <option value="Kódování">Kódování</option>
            <option value="Meeting">Meeting</option>
        </select>
        <input type="text" id="text-input" class="form-control mb-3" placeholder="Zadej text" name="text">
        <button value="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add Task</button>
    </div>
</form>

<table class="table table-striped">
    <tr class="bg-info">
        <th>Job</th>
        <th>Task</th>
        <th>Action</th>
    </tr>

    <tbody id="table">

    </tbody>
</table>

<script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/uuidv4.js"></script>
<script src="js/function.js"></script>
<script src="js/script.js"></script>
```

```html
<body>

    <h1>Table</h1>

    <form id="form-list">
        <div class="form-group mx-auto col-3" style="margin-top: 2rem;">
            <select name="selected" class="form-select">
                <option selected>Open this select menu</option>
                <option value="Programování">Programování</option>
                <option value="Kódování">Kódování</option>
                <option value="Meeting">Meeting</option>
            </select>
            <input type="text" id="text-input" class="form-control mb-3" placeholder="Zadej text" name="text">
            <button value="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add Task</button>
        </div>
    </form>

    <table class="table table-striped">
        <tr class="bg-info">
            <th>Job</th>
            <th>Task</th>
            <th>Action</th>
        </tr>

        <tbody id="table">

        </tbody>
    </table>

    <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/uuidv4.js"></script>
    <script src="js/function.js"></script>
    <script src="js/script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).